# Magento 1.9 - HTTP ERROR 500 and PHP Fatal error:

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, http-error-500

We recently moved to a new hosting company and they set our **Magento 1.9.1** website as parked on top of the main account's domain. It worked fine for about a week. We haven't made any changes and now we are getting the following Error when trying to access the website:

```
This page isn’t working `www.ourwebsite.com` is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500


PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /home/account/mydomain.com/includes/src/__default.php:28278    

Stack trace:
    #0 /home/account/mydomain.com/includes/src/__default.php(14070): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
    #1 /home/account/mydomain.com/app/code/local/Smartwave/Ajaxcatalog/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(111): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
    #2 /home/account/mydomain.com/includes/src/__default.php(14098): Smartwave_Ajaxcatalog_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
    #3 /home/account/mydomain.com/includes/src/__default.php(18482): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
    #4 /home/account/mydomain.com/includes/src/__default.php(18016): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #5 /home/account/mydomain.com/includes/src/__default.php(20808): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #6 /home/account/mydomain.com/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #7 / in /home/account/mydomain.com/includes/src/__default.php on line 28278
```

**The interesting part of this is that the main website which runs Magento 1.9.4 is up and running with no problems. It's the 2 parked domains/websites that run Magento 1.9.1 that have this issue.**

Answer (score 5):

It seems you're using the Magento Compiler. You'll need to refresh or disable. In my case, I prefer to disable the Compiler.

The easier way is using Magento shell. Go to the shell directory and then run:

```
php compiler.php state
```

Now you'll see the current status of or compiler. If is enabled and/or compiled then please execute these commands:

```
php compiler.php disable
php compiler.php clear
```

Now it is disabled and you've cleared all the generated files.

**I hope this will help**

Answer (score 1):

The compilation mode is enabled, thats way you see those errors.
Disable compilation: Go into :

> includes/config.php

and comment this line

```
-#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
```

To get rid of the error you need to disable the compilation in production , and clear the include directory created during compilation  includes/src.

```
php -f shell/compiler.php – clear
```